# Do you have to unsubscribe from a QueryList in a component?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

When using the `@ContentChildren` or `@ViewChildren` decorators to listen for changes to DOM elements. Do I have to unsubscribe from the `QueryList`?

For example:

```
@Component({...})
export class ParentComponent implements AfterContentInit {
    @ContentChildren(ChildComponent)
    public children: QueryList<ChildComponent>;

    public ngAfterContentInit(): void {
        this.children.changes.subscribe(() => ....);
    }
}
```

Would the above be a problem?

**Updated:**

The reason I'm asking is that we don't have to unsubscribe to `@Output` decorators. These are automatically unsubscribed by the component when it is destroyed.

I can not find any documentation which says this is the same for the `QueryList`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't have to unsubscribe from QueryList. It does it for you.

See here:
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7d137d7f8872a6fba72668e32f9baf2c5dcfc48b/packages/core/src/linker/query_list.ts#L115

As a general rule, I unsubscribe when Observable stays alive after Component destroyal. Works in most scenarios.

Comment: [This stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-simple-dropdown-hvvraw) shows that it does close automatically when the component is destroyed.

Answer (score -1):

As a general rule, it's good to unsubscribe from things that you have subscribed to when your component is destroyed. In Angular, you can do this in your ngOnDestroy method.

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({...})

export class ParentComponent implements AfterContentInit, OnDestroy {
    @ContentChildren(ChildComponent)
    public children: QueryList<ChildComponent>;
    private childrenSubscription: Subscription;

    public ngAfterContentInit(): void {
        this.childrenSubscription = this.children.changes.subscribe(() => ....);
    }

    public ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.childrenSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Comment: I know how to unsubscribe, but I'm asking if it is required. Will the `@ContentChildren` decorator handle it for us automatically?