# Angular6 AutoFocus using *ngIf

Tags: angular

```
<div class="dropdownContainer" placeholder="test" (click)="ShowDropDown()"  />

<div #tref *ngIf="showDropDown == 1" class="dropdownList" (focusout)="HideDropDown()" style="border:1px solid black;" >this is my test</div>
```

After clicking  the dropDownContainer i would like the dropdownList to appear and have focus put on it.

I Have tried using

```
  @ViewChild("tref", {read: ElementRef}) tref: ElementRef;
```

method, but it returns undefined because that element doesnt exist in the DOM until the above `div` is clicked. How can I autofocus on a dynamic *NON INPUT* DOM object?

***EDIT*** Updated my code per suggestions, this still will not autofocus on the div.

```
  @ViewChild("tref") tref: ElementRef;
      ShowDropDown() {
      this.showDropDown = 1;
      this.tref.nativeElement.focus();
      console.log(this.tref);
  }
HideDropDown(){
  console.log('test out')
  this.showDropDown = 0;
}



<input   #tref class="dropdownContainer" placeholder="george" (click)="ShowDropDown()"  />
<div tabindex="-1" (focusout)="HideDropDown()" [hidden]="showDropDown == 0" class="dropdownList"  style="border:1px solid black;" >this is my test</div>
```

***ANSWER TO THE PROBLEM***
Two fold answer.

1) DIVS cannot have focus unless they have tabindex. [Stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599660/which-html-elements-can-receive-focus)

2)I need to include `setTimeout(() => this.tref.nativeElement.focus(), 1);` because an element that is `hidden` is not automatically ready to receive focus.

3)*ngIf and hidden both worked, once i put in the above fixes

Cleaned up code

```
import { Component,  ElementRef , ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.less']
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor() {
  }

  showDropDown = 0;



  @ViewChild("tref") tref: ElementRef;
  ShowDropDown() {
this.showDropDown = 1;
setTimeout(() => this.tref.nativeElement.focus(), 1);
  }

HideDropDown(){
  this.showDropDown = 0;
}

test(){ console.log('works');}

}

<div tabindex="-2"    class="dropdownContainer" placeholder="george" (click)="ShowDropDown()"   ></div>
<div tabindex="-1" #tref [hidden]="showDropDown == 0" class="dropdownList"  style="border:1px solid black;" (click)="test()" (focusout)="HideDropDown()">this is my test</div>
```

Comment: Try with <div tabindex="-1" *ngIf="showDropDown

Comment: There should be a way to make it work with `ngIf`, and without `setTimeout`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan you are correct hidden is not needed, i will update my post

Comment: You also don't need `setTimeout`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can focus the dropdown element as soon as it becomes visible, with the help of `ViewChildren` and the `QueryList.changes` event. This technique works no matter how long it takes for the element to appear in the view.

In the template, give a `tabindex` attribute to the dropdown `div`:

```
<div class="dropdownContainer" (click)="showDropDown = true">
  Click here to show the dropdown
</div>

<div #dropDownDiv *ngIf="showDropDown" tabindex="1" class="dropdownList" (focusout)="showDropDown = false">
  This is the dropdown element
</div>
```

In code, retrieve the dropdown element with `ViewChildren`, and set the `QueryList.changes` event handler in `ngAfterViewInit`. When you are notified that the element has become visible, you can set the focus on it:

```
showDropDown = false;

@ViewChildren("dropDownDiv") private dropDownDivList: QueryList<ElementRef>;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.dropDownDivList.changes.subscribe((list: QueryList<ElementRef>) => {
    if (list.length > 0) {
      list.first.nativeElement.focus();
    }
  });
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-txho39) for a demo.

Comment: would I need to unsubscribe on destroy?

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51392628/1009922), you wouldn't have to. I made a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-simple-dropdown-hvvraw) to show that it closes automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Change from `*ngIf="showDropDown"` to `[hidden]="! showDropDown"` and you should be able to use @ViewChild inside the component and prevent the "undefiend" issue.

If that still didn't work, you could always pass the element to the component through the click event by changing the click to this `(click)="ShowDropDown(tref)"`. Note that in order for this to work, you'd still need to change *ngIf to [hidden].

Comment: Thank you for the help, but it still wont autofocus on the div

Comment: @gh9 Check the answers here > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38307060/how-to-set-focus-on-element-with-binding

Comment: Thank you very much! that worked I will also update my post with what worked

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: No problem. I will leave this answer here for my 10 points :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a common container for both elements, and set the focusout on the container, the dropdown will be hidden on any click, including clicks on the dropdown element - without having to manually set the focus. (note we have to set the tabindex on the parent).

```
<div class="container" (focusout)="showDropDown = false" tabindex="0">
  <div class="dropdownContainer" (click)="showDropDown = true">
    Click here to show the dropdown
  </div>

  <div #dropDownDiv *ngIf="showDropDown" tabindex="1" class="dropdownList" >
    This is the dropdown element
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```